# Not getting Elevation with Pydeck

Tags: python, visualization, layer, streamlit, pydeck

I have a DataSet like following and I want to represent in a pydeck layer map the column n_cases:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZkRr.png)

I am doing in this way, but i never get elevation in the hexagons, have tried with lot of elevation ranges and elevation scales:

```
r = pdk.Deck(map_style=None,
        initial_view_state=pdk.ViewState(
        latitude=provincias_map['latitude'].mean(),
        longitude=provincias_map['longitude'].mean(),
        zoom=5,
        pitch=45),
        layers=[
        pdk.Layer(
           'HexagonLayer',
           data=provincias_map,
           get_position='[longitude, latitude]',
           get_elevation = 'n_cases',
           radius=18000,
           elevation_scale=20,
           elevation_range=[0, 1780000],
           pickable=True,
           extruded=True,
           coverage = 1,
        )])
```

[map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr7F6.png)

Comment: Hi, have noticed right now, that if i PIck on an hexagon, ElevationValue is always 1.

Answer (score 1):

Set the get_elevation_weight option to 'n_cases' to have the computed elevation value as the correlated 'n_cases' value of the data point.

```py
max_range = int(provincias_map['n_cases'].max())

r = pdk.Deck(map_style=None,
        initial_view_state=pdk.ViewState(
        latitude=provincias_map['latitude'].mean(),
        longitude=provincias_map['longitude'].mean(),
        zoom=5,
        pitch=45),
        layers=[
        pdk.Layer(
           'HexagonLayer',
           data=provincias_map,
           get_position='[longitude, latitude]',
           get_elevation_weight = 'n_cases',
           radius=18000,
           elevation_scale=1,
           elevation_range=[0, max_range],
           pickable=True,
           extruded=True,
           coverage = 1,
        )])
```